# line rotation in class javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I try to create a class with a function which might be use to change the angle of a line already drawn.
With what I write, the line doesn't move. When I press the right or left key, I have this error :

> TypeError: this.changeAngle is not a function

Indeed, I don't have "function" keyword in my code ... I don't know what to use instead.

Could you help me ?
Thank you very much.

```
window.onload = init;

let canvas, ctx;
let mousePos;
let angle = 0;


class Lanceur {
  constructor() {    
    this.changeAngle(this.angle);
  }

  update(ctx) {
    this.drawAiguille(ctx);
  }

  drawSocleLanceur(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.arc(w/2, h, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

  drawAiguille(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.rotate(this.angle);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(w/2, h-h*0.12);
    ctx.lineTo(w/2, h-h*0.035);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  }


  changeAngle(a) {
      this.angle =  a;
  }

  getAngle() {
      return this.angle;
  }

}

function init() {
  canvas = document.querySelector("#jeu");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;

  a = new Lanceur();
      requestAnimationFrame(mainloop);
  }

function mainloop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  a.update(ctx);
  requestAnimationFrame(mainloop);
}

document.addEventListener('keypress',  function(event){
    gereTouches(event);
});


function gereTouches(event) {
  if(event.key == "ArrowRight") {
    this.changeAngle(this.getAngle - 1);
      console.log("ça bouge : " + this.angle);
  }else if(event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    this.changeAngle(this.getAngle + 1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main changes:

- added this.angle to thr constructor()
- using `keydown` event
- the function gereTouches(event) uses `a` instead of `this` and `a.getAngle()` instead of `a.getAngle`
- also 1 for the the angle is way too big (those are radians). I'm using .01 instead.

I hope it helps.

```js
window.onload = init;

let canvas, ctx;
let mousePos;
let angle = 0;


class Lanceur {
  constructor() { 
    this.angle = 0;
    this.changeAngle(this.angle);
  }

  update(ctx) {
    this.drawAiguille(ctx);
  }

  drawSocleLanceur(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.arc(w/2, h, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

  drawAiguille(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.rotate(this.angle);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(w/2, h-h*0.12);
    ctx.lineTo(w/2, h-h*0.035);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  }


  changeAngle(a) {
      this.angle =  a;
  }

  getAngle() {
      return this.angle;
  }

}

function init() {
  canvas = document.querySelector("#jeu");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  w = canvas.width = 500;
  h = canvas.height = 500;

  a = new Lanceur();
  requestAnimationFrame(mainloop);
  }

function mainloop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  a.update(ctx);
  requestAnimationFrame(mainloop);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',  function(event){
  
    gereTouches(event);
});


function gereTouches(event) {
  if(event.key == "ArrowRight") {
    a.changeAngle(a.getAngle() - .01);
      console.log("ça bouge : " + a.angle);
  }else if(event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    a.changeAngle(a.getAngle() + .01);
}
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="jeu"></canvas>
```

Comment: If you need to *really* rotate the `Aiguille` you need to draw it in the origin of your canvas rotate and translate